# Run exec task as input for configuration phase

Tags: git, gradle, groovy

I want to write a version string in my manifest file using Gradle. For this I use `git describe`. To get this string, I wrote a `exec` task:

```
task gitVersion(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'git', 'describe'
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
  }
}
```

It works if I use it to process the resources, for example:

```
processResources {
  dependsOn gitVersion
  filesMatching('build.properties') {
    expand 'buildVersion': "${gitVersion.output()}"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work if I try this in the `jar` task.

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      // Other attributes
      'Implementation-Version': "${gitVersion.output()}" // Not working
    )
  }
}
```

As I understood the [Gradle Build Lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), it is because the `jar` task is "configuration phase" and the `exec` task is "execution phase".

Is there a way I can execute the `exec` task in the configuration phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "GString lazy evaluation" Groovy feature (see some details/examples [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions)) :

```
jar{
    manifest {
        attributes( 
            'Implementation-Version': "${->gitVersion.output()}" // use " ${->prop} syntax for lazy evaluation
        )
    }
}
```